# Can WiFi packets be sniffed/decrypted if you don't have access to the network?

Tags: wifi

I have multiple devices connected to a router, including my phone. The router has no internet; therefore, the network only works locally. All nodes can talk with each other thanks to the router. I use my phone to send messages to the nodes.

If no one has access to the WiFi password will it be possible for someone to sniff the udp messages that I send over the network? If I host a small website in that enclosed network will HTTP traffic be secure? Will you guys recommend using HTTPS even though I am the only one that will use the network?

Pretend that if instead of using wifi, the network is wired. If I were to read the 0s and 1s from a cable, will the messages be encrypted even though they are simple HTTP requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are not using any security at all on your Wifi, no. Nobody but those connected can read anything. Please don't tell me your network is unprotected.

If you have your network "protected" by WEP, someone can crack the password in minutes, and begin decrypting the traffic. But if you use WPA2, it's very difficult. No matter what protection you have, unless the attacker gets your network password, they cannot read anything but encrypted blobs of data. No matter if UDP or TCP, they cannot.

On a cable things are different. If they tap into the wires, they can read all unencrypted traffic. All HTTP traffic is plaintext, and all non-encrypted protocol as well (FTP, SMTP, DNS, telnet).

Comment: It may be worth mentioning, that all WiFi traffic an be intercepted (whether encrypted or not). Thus an adversary may create an activity profile from the target network, even if the can not read the actual messages.

Comment: but it's mentioned: "unless the attacker gets your network password, they cannot read anything but encrypted blobs of data."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your wireless traffic can be captured without connecting to your network. If it is unencrypted, an attacker may read it. HTTPS traffic is always encrypted. Whether HTTP traffic is encrypted depends on the configuration of your wireless access point, which in your case seems to be integrated into the SOHO router.

The same goes for intercepted wireless communications. If they are securely encrypted, they will not be readable. If they are unencrypted, they will be readable. It is a bit more effort /more intrusive to tap into the wire than to sniff wireless traffic though.

In any medium, encryption may be configured. WPA2 for your wireless is available on most SOHO routers from the last decade.

Comment: Unless the network has no protection at all, even HTTP traffic cannot be read. The attacker cannot even know it's HTTP at all.

Comment: "No protection at all" is not an accurate description of a network with unencrypted traffic.

Comment: and what protection does an unencrypted network have? Anyone can read and alter traffic at will.

Comment: No, a lack of confidentiality does not imply a lack of integrity. You cannot assume that traffic can be altered just because it may be read, even though it is sometimes the case that traffic can be both read and altered.

Comment: Ever heard of ARP spoofing?

Comment: There are undoubtedly problems which arise from insecure networks. However, encryption is not a solution to all your security needs, nor is encryption necessary as a precondition for every security measure. A network which does not encrypt all traffic need not have "no protection at all", even if it is possible for the situations to coincide.

Comment: In the case of wireless networks, *no encryption* and *no protection at all* are the same thing. No integrity, no confidentiality, no way to know if you know who you are talking to, no way to know if the message you received wasn't altered, or who really sent it, or the message you sent was received at all.

Comment: Encryption contributes to confidentiality. Encryption does not provide integrity. A message authentication code attached to an unencrypted message ensures its integrity. Encryption has a specific definition and does not simply mean "protection" in general.